# Extra space character appearing when I use 'ç' via content on CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am inserting some content through the `content` property in my CSS file. When I have the `ç` character, I get an extra space. It ends up looking like this:

[image]

So you can see there is an extra space, that is not supposed to be there and only appears if I use the `ç` character.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
&#some-id{
  a:before {
    content: "Français";
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this by using the `content` CSS attribute?
Edit: as requested, here is some of the HTML code where it is used (it is on the `li` tag and I should probably note, I am using bootstrap:

```
<section id='top' className='row'>
  <div className='col-sm-12 light'>
    <div className='valign'>
      <div>
        <ul className='row'>
          <li id='some-id' className='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
            <a href='/somewhere'>
              <h2>Content Header</h2>
              <p>More content</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show the specific HTML code? You may need to use a special character: https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Comment: Which font is used?

Comment: it's all about the font used, so we need it

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be working fine. Can you post more of your code?

```css
#some-id a:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  content: "Français";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id='top' className='row'>
  <div className='col-sm-12 light'>
    <div className='valign'>
      <div>
        <ul className='row'>
          <li id='some-id' className='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
            <a href='/somewhere'>
              <h2>Content Header</h2>
              <p>More content</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Updated example

Comment: Can you post your index source? I want to see what other stylesheets you're including. You have to be experiencing CSS collisions from some other include.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ascii version of that letter and then convert it using this: http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html

```css
  p:before {
    content: "Fran\00E7 ais";
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: If I do it that way, I still get the extra space, and if I remove the space, obviously I get the unknown character square. Is there another way to separate the special character from the rest of the string?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like something else must be influencing your css since in the example above, it works just fine. What other css packages are you using?

Comment: Just bootstrap and another tone of CSS which we are using throughout the app.